# Getting Errors when using Enum with JSON (Swift)

Tags: json, swift, string, enums, decodable

I am trying to use `Decodable` with an `Enum` but I have four of errors in my `Enum` that state: ***Raw value for enum case must be a literal***.  I'm new to handling JSON data and I'm not sure how to get this to work.

```
import UIKit

enum BusinessType : String, Decodable {
    case pizza = String 
    case seafood = String
    case greek = String
    case vegan = String
}

struct Address : Decodable {
    var street : String
    var city : String
    var state : String
    var businessType : BusinessType
}

struct Customer : Decodable {
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String
    var address : Address
}

struct CustomersResponse : Decodable {
    var customers : [Customer]
}


let json = """

{
    "customers":[
        {
            "firstName" : "My",
            "lastName" : "Client",
            "address" : {
                "street" : "100 Business Address",
                "city" : "New York",
                "state" : "NY",
                "businessType" : "pizza"
            }
        }

    ]

}

""".data(using: .utf8)!

let customersResponse = try! 
JSONDecoder().decode(CustomersResponse.self, from: json)
print(customersResponse)
```

Comment: `case pizza = String` This doesn't make sense. Just write `case pizza` (for all of them).

Comment: I thought that it would be `String` because of how it looks in the `Structs`. It made sense to me at the time. Why would I put `case pizza` for all of the different foods? You must mean `case` and then the respective food.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, a `literal` is the actual `String` rather than it's `type`. Try this ...

```
enum BusinessType : String, Decodable {
    case pizza = "pizza"
    case seafood = "seafood"
    case greek = "greek"
    case vegan = "vegan"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify type of raw value as `String`, you don't have to write its raw value since default value is name of the case

```
enum BusinessType : String, Decodable {
    case pizza, seafood, greek, vegan
}
```